# set auto_increament to entity field in composite primary key (@EmbeddedId)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class for Table1. Table1 has got composite primary key with 3 columns and one of them (id) is defined as auto-increment in table.

Below is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private Table1PK id;
}
```

and Table1PK code is:

```
@Embeddable
public class Table1PK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

I understand that @GeneratedValue would not work for the composite key (for @EmbeddedId).

Can anyone please help how I can make this id(in above Table1PK) as auto_increment (as this is auto_increment in table)

Comment: See the answer here. If the Column X is auto-increment then that in itself can be used as an Identifer. JPA `@Id` does not need to match the DB PK column(s) - it just has to be unique. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37456682/1356423

Comment: Thanks, its working now.