# @GeneratedValue in @Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, embeddable

I have separated the id of an entity into a separate @Embeddable class.

The Entity is given below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {
@EmbeddedId
private Users_pk id;
private String username;
//getters and setters follow
```

The @Embeddable class is:

```
@Embeddable
public class Users_pk implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
@Column(name="idusers")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
//getters and setters follow
```

I try to persist the users object using the code below:

```
public class HibernateTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
Users user = new Users();
user.setId(new Users_pk());
//setting other attributes of user and calling the save method
```

This code works fine if the "hbm2ddl.auto" property is set to create and the user gets created with id 0, if however after this is done I change the property value to 'update' and run the same code again, I get the below exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

So, the Generated strategy is not working in @Embeddable object.
This seems to be an [existing bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260983) that was resolved earlier.
Also, a similar question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448621/embeddedid-with-generatedvalue-in-embeddable)

any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.3 with Java 1.8 in Eclipse