# How to use @GeneratedValue inside @Embeddable used as composite primary key?

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, composite, auto-generate

I have in my data base one table with primary composite key, when I model it with Hibernate I use `@EmbeddedId` & `@Embedable`. One column of this composite primary key have a generated value with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

When I try to create two new object in my data base I have an error like this :

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [MyPackage#MyEmbedableClass [MyGeneratedPrimaryKeyValue=null, OtherPrimaryKey=21]]
```

But when I look in my data base my objects have been created. I don't understand my mistakes and I don't know how solve my problem.

I have found some topics like mine but I haven't found answer to my question.

1. [first exemple](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-5-and-using-generatedvalue-inside-embeddable-annotated-objects-used-as-composite-primary-keys/3091)
2. [second exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51639323/generatedvalue-in-embeddable)
3. [third exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448621/embeddedid-with-generatedvalue-in-embeddable)

```java
@Entity(name = "Certification")
@Table(name = "CERTIFICATION")
public class Certification implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = -4399907743392740963L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CertificationPK certificationPK;

    // Others variables
    // constructors
    // Getter / Setter
    // toString
    // hashCode / equals
}

@Embeddable
public class CertificationPK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1433990897506209802L;

    // MyGeneratedPrimaryKeyValue=null when I create
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CERTIFICATION_ID")
    private Integer certificationId; 

    // Other variable
    // constructors
    // Getter / Setter
    // toString
    // hashCode / equals
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show your mapping.

Comment: @SternK What do you mean by mapping ?

Comment: *when I modelise it with Hibernate I use @EmbeddedId & @Embedable* - please show how you modelise it

Comment: @SternK I updated my post, if you need more I can add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It looks like you can not use `@GeneratedValue` with `@EmbeddedId`. You can find some workaround in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) but it did not work well for me.
2. As it's stated in [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated) section of documentation, it should be possible to use `@GeneratedValue` with `@IdClass`. But, it does not work due to [HHH-9662](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9662).
3. As it's stated in [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-generated) section of documentation:

> When using composite identifiers, the underlying identifier properties must be manually assigned by the user.
>
> Automatically generated properties are not supported to be used to generate the value of an underlying property that makes the composite identifier.
>
> Therefore, you cannot use any of the automatic property generator described by the [generated properties](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated) section like `@Generated`, `@CreationTimestamp` or `@ValueGenerationType` or database-generated values.
>
> Nevertheless, you can still generate the identifier properties prior to constructing the composite identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your correction !