# JPA - Mapping Composite Primary Key OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose there are 2 entities, which represent a blog Post and its comments. One blog can have multiple comments:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "post")
   private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(CommentPK.class)
public class Comment {

  @Id
  private Long id;  

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  private Post post;

  private String content;
}

class CommentPK implements Serializable {
   private Long post;
   private Long id;
}
```

I want Comment to have composite PK of (post_id, comment_id), where comment_id is a sequence within one post, for example:

```
| post_id | comment_id | content  |
| 1       | 1          | 123      |
| 1       | 2          | 456      |
| 1       | 3          | Hello SO |
| 2       | 1          | New Post | << Post #2 has comment IDs starting from 1 again
```

While mapping works, I can not save post, because comment does not have ID. This is why I've added entity listeners:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
public void preProcess(Post post) {
  int id = 1;
  for (Comment comment : post.getComments()) {
    comment.setPost(post);
    comment.setId(id++);
  }
}
```

It works on the first post persist, however if I add new comments to persisted post, entity listener is not called. I have also tried adding entity listener for Comment with the similar logic, but it is just not not invoked

```
@Test
public void testPersistAndUpdate() {
  Post post = new Post();
  post.setName("Test");

  Comment comment1 = new Comment();
  comment1.setPost(post);
  comment1.setContent("Comment 1");

  List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
  comments.add(comment1);
  post.setComments(comments);

  Post savedPost = postRepository.saveAndFlush(post); // Spring Data JPA repository, all OK for now
  
  // create new Comment
  Comment comment2 = new Comment();
  comment2.setPost(post);
  comment2.setContent("Comment 2");

  savedPost.getComments().add(comment2);
  savedPost = postRepository.saveAndFlush(savedPost); // here entity listener is not invoked and exception is thrown

}
```

I am getting an exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null

#### Questions

1. What is the common practice of modeling relations like these? (still keeping composite key a requirement) As it feels pretty uncomfortable dealing with it through JPA/Hibernate now
2. If keeping the mapping from the example, is it possible to make `@PrePersist` for `Comment` working, when `Post` attributes are not updated, but the `Comment` is new and should be persisted?

---

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that usage of [JPA Callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks) is a proper approach for your problem (See also [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/are-jpa-callback-methods)). I would suggest you to use [@MapsId](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation. You can correct the mapping in the following way:

```java
@Entity
public class Post {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "post")
   private List<Comment> comments;
}

@Entity
public class Comment {

  @EmbeddedId
  CommentPK id;
  

  @MapsId("post")
  @ManyToOne
  private Post post;

  // 
}

@Embeddable
class CommentPK implements Serializable {
   private Long post;
   private Long id;
   
   // getters, setters, equals, hashCode
}
```

The `CommentPK.post` value will be derived from the `Comment.post` association.

Comment: This will not generate `comment.id.id` value. How should I set it? I am using JPA callbacks for it now.

Comment: May by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377401/6277104) will be helpful. But I would suggest you to ask yourself: *Why do you want Comment to have composite PK*?

Comment: I think it is more correct from the domain point of view. Comment is identified by post it belongs to and its sequential number. In addition, it allows me to make queries like "get all comments for specific post" without additional indices

Comment: I don't think that this approach will bring benefit, only overhead complexity. Comments can easily have hierarchical structure that will break your sequential model. IMHO, the approach with simple PK for Comments and FK for Post looks much more simple / transparent for further support / extension.