# possible alternatives to @GeneratedValue with @EmbeddedId in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My entity has a wrapped Identifier like this,

```
@Entity
public class Article {
   
   @EmbeddedId
   private ArticleId articleId;

   ....
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class ArticleId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

}
```

in my architecture, multiple application instances(it all same.) are connected to the same data source
so `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`seems good
because even if instances A and B try to create `Account`at the same time, Its Id is guaranteed by the database.

problem is that `@GeneratedValue` is only able to use with `@Id` annotation (`@Id` is not available for `EmbeddedId`)

`PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(Object entity)` could be a alternative? like this,

```
ArticleId articleId = ArticleRepository.nextIdentity();
```

I am not sure that whether it causes the race condition.
Could `PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(Object entity)` guarantee the unique id across the different application instance(JVM)? I don't think so.

In this situation, What alternative is possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377401/6277104) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use an `@IdClass` to get rid of the nested property and be able to generate the identifier (since nested properties are "assigned" and cannot be generated, so the call of `PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(Object entity)` would not help here). See e.g. [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for a complete guide (also linked in the linked answer by @SternK from the comment)

An `@IdClass` could look like this:

```
public class ArticleId implements Serializable {
  private Long id;
}
```

An entity could use it:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ArticleId.class) // specified dependency
public class Article {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  // expose "typed" id:
  public ArticleId getId() {
    return new ArticleId(id);
  }
}
```

Spring-Data `@Repository`s also work with corresponding `@IdClass` objects, e.g.:

```
@Repository
public interface UserEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, ArticleId> {
}

// would offer e.g. this method:
repository.findById(new ArticleId(123L));
```

Comment: I also initially considered a compound identifier, but there is no good reason to make a composite identifier.
My first approach was to use two Identity (referred to IDDD, vaughn vernon). 
one for the domain model as a UUID(unique id across the different JVM), 
the other is surrogate Identity for database (Surrogate Identity is hidden in the inheritance hierarchy).
I just want to use one numeric sequence Id, but there seems to be no way with hibernate.
I decided not to create a typed ID but use it as a primitive long id because I think the complexity will increase.

Comment: the `@IdClass` approach also works with only one (generated) field!
so you could also implement a typed ID (e.g. the wrapped Long) that way, without the need to have additional `@Id` fields in the `@IdClass` (adjusted the sample code)

Comment: I meant 'typed-Id' as `MediaAccountId.class`, not `Long.class`.
I wanted to create clear a dependency on `MediaAccountId.class`not primitive `long` or  `Long.class`.

Comment: I updated the answer, even if the entity has an "untyped" field (which is generated), it is at least publically exposed as the "typed" id, is that close to what you liked to achieve?

Comment: Yes, It is close to what I want to achieve. I think that your answer is another implementation of surrogate Identity. I could hide `Long id` for the JPA mechanism in the Inheritance hierarchy and I remain only `ArticleId` in the domain model. (even if annotations related to the JPA mechanism remain in the domain model, I allow an annotation. For ease of implementation. e.g @Transactional)