# EmbeddedId with Generated value in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a customer entity whose primary is a composite key. In the composite key one of the field is auto generated value.

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
public class Customer {
 
  @EmbeddedId
  private CustomerId customerId;


  @Size(max = 255)
  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;
```

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomerId implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8048935613697415032L;
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
  private Long accountId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
}
```

When i use below snippet of code to save the customer, the record gets saved succesfully in db BUT fails to retrieve the saved.getCustomerId().getId() --> null. Any ideas to fix this?

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Customer sc,
                             @RequestParam long account_id) {
  sc.setCustomerId(CustomerId.builder().accountId(account_id).build());
  Customer saved = customerRepository.saveAndFlush(sc);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(saved);
}
```

Tried with EmbededdId/ IdClass. Both does not help

Comment: `getId()` method is executed on instance of `SalesContact`. Please provide `SalesContact` code

Comment: @AleksanderSzporka, its Customer only. updated now.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377401/9135271 you cannot use `@GeneratedValue` with `@EmbeddedId`.

You could use e.g. `UUID` for `CustomerId_ID`

```
    @NotNull
    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Please note that `@Builder.Default` is required as you want to initialize `CustomerId` with `CustomerId.builder().accountId(account_id).build()`

P.S. I have to add `@NoArgsConstructor` to `Customer` to make your sample code working