# Autogenerated field of embedded id is null after JPA persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have a class structure made up of a main class (called `MaterialResource`) that has an embedded id (called `MaterialResourceId`). Note also that the `MaterialResourceId` class has two fields: `idMaterialResource` and `idCompany`. `idMaterialResource` is **autogenerated** with strategy identity.

The problem is that when I persist a `MaterialResource` object (with `idMaterialResource` set to `null`, as it should be auto-generated) the database insertion works perfectly, but the returned object has the `idMaterialResource` field set to `null` too. This way I cannot know what id (what number) has been assigned to my newly created object.

The classes are the following. This is the main class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "material_resource")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MaterialResource {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MaterialResourceId materialResourceId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name = "";
    ...
}
```

This is its embedded id:

```java
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MaterialResourceId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_materialresource")
    private Integer idMaterialResource;

    @Column(name = "id_company")
    private Integer idCompany;
}
```

(Note that I'm using the `lombok` annotations to generate getters, setters, equals, hashCode...)

Now, if I try to execute:

```
MaterialResourceId id = new MaterialResourceId(null, 1);
MaterialResource materialResource = MaterialResource(id, "Material resource name", ...);
getEntityManager().persist(materialResource);
```

(Note that all the previous code is placed inside an entity manager transaction)

It turns out that `materialResource.materialResourceId.idMaterialResource` is `null`. As I said, this is a problem since I cannot know which id has been assigned. Thus, I cannot return to the client the id of the created object, I cannot find the object in the database...

However, if I inspect the database with an external app (DBeaver), a row in the `MaterialResource` table has been properly created (with an autogenerated value for `idMaterialResource`).

The Flyway script for creating the `MaterialResource` table is the following (here is where I set `id_materialresource` to be auto-generated).

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS material_resource(
    id_materialresource INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_company INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
    identifier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
    fromDate DATE NOT NULL,
    toDate DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_recurso, id_empresa)
);
```

Any help is useful. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't find an object in the database then it is not created. You should provide a debugging details.

Comment: I forgot to explain this. The objects are perfectly created in the database (with the auto-generated id). I'm editing the post.

Comment: Persist is a no-op. The insert statement is only required to be performed when the context is synchronized to the database - when it is flushed or the transaction commits. Your entity won't have an Id assigned until after the insert when using identity, so you can force a flush or look at the managed entity instance after the transaction commits. Also note, JPA's EntityManager's Persist method doesn't return anything. What you pass in becomes the managed entity instance, so I don't quite know what you are calling or showing in your question, but it isn't a JPA method.

Comment: That's true, I'm correcting the question. What I wanted to say is: after the `persist`, if I look at the managed entity, one of the fields of the composed id is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I have found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377401/7277672). Basically, auto-generated composed ids are currently not supported in Hibernate.